# Proof of the boundedness theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**Proof of the boundedness theorem**

[image: 1]

I am new to this subject so can anyone please explain $f(x_{n_k})>n_k \geq k$ ? I can't understand  $n_k \geq k$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are choosing a **sub**sequence, you may "jump" some terms, thus $n_k\geq k$.

For example, the orignal sequence (the first line represents $k$)$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  \cdots\\
 a_1&  a_2&  a_3&  a_4&  a_5&  a_6&  a_7&  \cdots\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
$$
One subsequece of it (also the first line represents $k$ and second line is $a_{n_k}$):
$$
\\
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  \cdots\\
 a_1&  a_2&  a_4&  a_5&  a_6&  a_7&  a_9&  \cdots\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
\\$$
Then it's clear that $1=1,2=2,4>3,5>4,6>5,7>6,9>7...$

Comment: is it always possible for subsequence?

Comment: What do you mean by "possible"? I added an example just now.

Comment: got it Thank you